# Making elements change without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I need to make something like this happen - http://jsfiddle.net/3nk8x98g/1/ everything is explained in the link.

What do I use Javascript or AJAX? And maybe someone knows a tutorial or something out there? Thanks.

```
    <body>

   <div class="row">
       <a href="#">BUTTON1</a>
       <a href="#">BUTTON2</a>
       <a href="#">BUTTON3</a>
   </div>

   <div class="row background">
       Changing content, this content changes depending on which button you press. Without refreshing the page.  
   </div>

</body>
```

Comment: *"What do I use Javascript or AJAX?"* - You would use Javascript, yes. And possibly Ajax, which would involve writing Javascript code to make an Ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this. Ajax is just for getting data from server without refreshing but you have to use javascript to attach that content to html dynamically.

```
$('a').on('click', function(){
    $('#changeingDiv').html('Changed Content');
}
);
```

this is just for example. Bind an event to the buttons, and on its click change the content of the div. For different content on different button click you can add id to them and change the content accordingly on some condition.

http://jsfiddle.net/3nk8x98g/2/

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is just a JavaScript technique, so yet, you need to use AJAX and JavaScript. Look at this for examples of how to achieve it using JavaScript only.

```
<body>
   <div class="row">
     <a id="one" href="#">BUTTON1</a>
     <a id="two" href="#">BUTTON2</a>
     <a id="three" href="#">BUTTON3</a>
   </div>
   <div id="content" class="row background">
     Changing content, this content changes depending on which button you press. Without refreshing the page.  
   </div>
   <script>
     var one = document.getElementById("one");
     var two = document.getElementById("two");
     var three = document.getElementById("three");
     var content = document.getElementById("content");

     one.addEventListener("click", function() { 
       content.innerHTML = "One";
     });

     two.addEventListener("click", function() {
       content.innerHTML = "Two";
     });

     threee.addEventListener("click", function() {
       content.innerHTML = "Three";
     });
    </script>
</body>
```